# What is the difference between privilege escalation and authorization bypass?

Tags: privilege-escalation

As I understand when a user with low privilege does some actions only available for users with high privilege this is called privilege escalation.

And authorization bypass is when I do some actions which I don't have the permissions to do, if I'm not mistaken.

What is the difference?

Comment: Have you done any googling? This is answered with a simple search.

Comment: ^ and consider the case where a user bypasses authentication to access data or actions of another user that has the same privilege level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These terms focus on different aspects of the attack: privilege escalation describes **what was achieved**, i.e. gaining higher privileges, no matter how. Authorization bypass describes **how things were done**, i.e. by bypassing the authorization, no matter what was gained this way.